# "A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol"

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular6

I am receiving this error when building a C# web api backend and angular 6 frontend in one Visual Studio solution. I am using VS 2015 for this. These errors are coming from the node modules in `@angular\core\src\interfaces` and `@angular\core\src\sanitization`

When using just the front end or just the back end, they both individually run fine. But the back end will not build if the front end is included in the VS project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I think we need more information before we can provide a meaningful answer.  Please review "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and what constitutes a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you get the error in some cases but not others, but I can tell you that error will go away if you upgrade to TypeScript 2.7 or newer.  Go to the [downloads page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/#download-links) and install the latest download for Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I tried that, as well as deleting and re-installing the node modules, but no dice, same errors.

Comment: The “A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol” message does not exist in TypeScript 2.7 and newer, so you must be using an older version of TypeScript somewhere.  What version of `typescript` is specified in your `package.json`?  If you can publish a repository that reproduces the problem for you, I will look at it; I don't have Visual Studio but if the problem is with a command-line Angular build, I can likely reproduce that.

Comment: In the package.json, I have `"typescript": "^2.7.2"`
both in devDependencies and dependencies

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I can do anything more unless you publish a repository.

Answer (score 0):

Download latest typescript version from visual studio ,https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=55258

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya This is not a link-only answer. Even though it's short and contains a link, it provides an answer to the question: "Download latest typescript version from visual studio" (and provides the official download link).  For more detailed guidance on what is considered a link-only answer, see [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/258777).